# Unexpected behaviour of static variable of StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an app containing some containers in a row. Upon clicking any container, it should disappear from screen. Following is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App!!',
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Example App'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    CC.L[0] = CC(x: 0,);
    CC.L[1] = CC(x: 1,);
    CC.L[2] = CC(x: 2,);
    Timer adderTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (_) {
      setState(() {
            });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Built');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            for (var cc in CC.L.values) cc
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CC extends StatefulWidget {
  const CC({super.key, required this.x});
  static Map L={};
  final int x;

  @override
  State<CC> createState() => _CCState();
}

class _CCState extends State<CC> {

  late String s = widget.x.toString();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(s);
    print(CC.L);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: ()=>setState(() {
              for (var cc in CC.L.keys){
                if (cc==widget.x){
                  print('removed ' + widget.x.toString());
                  CC.L.remove(cc);
                  print(CC.L);
                }
              }
            }),
       child: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey.shade900,
          ),
          child: Text(s),
       )
    );
   
  }
}
```

When any container is clicked, respective Map element/Widget instance is deleted, it prints the Map after deleting correctly as expected, but when building widgets based on that Map something else shows (if i click on 1, its deleted and 0,2 are showed when printing Map but after updating state, containers with 0,1 values show up).

Also, am I using static variable in a wrong way or is there any way to write it better?
Also, I've to make a timer to call setState of MyApp at regular intervals... Is there any way to call MyApp's setState from within _CCState whenever element is deleted.

Tried printing current Map values, the deleted value, but still doesnt match with UI.

Comment: try `CC(key: ValueKey(0), x: 0,);` and do the similar with other `CC`s

Comment: @pskink That worked like a charm! Thanks!!

Comment: your welcome, more here: https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc?si=anJDn2Byj-fA4DwY